# Algorithm to find sets of vertices connected to at most one incoming and one outgoing vertex outside the set

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have a directed graph with vertices $V$, and I need to find a strict subset $U$ of its vertices such that:

1. $U$ contains at least two vertices, and $U \neq V$
2. There is at most one vertex in $V \setminus U$ connected to a vertex in $U$
3. There is at most one vertex in $U$ connected to a vertex in $V \setminus U$

(assuming there is such a subset).

The current algorithm I have works by recursively calling itself with one added vertex until the set has the appropriate conditions, but it's much too slow.

Is there any algorithm I could use to do this more efficiently?

Comment: By "guessing" _U_, you get a running time of _2^n_.  Have you tried to see what happens if you **"know" the "entry-point" and "exit-point"** of _U_?  If you can solve it then in _p(n, m)_ time, then the algorithm takes _n² p(n, m)_ in total.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful, I didn't think about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's name the vertices $v \in V \setminus U$ and $u \in U$ the vertices that are allowed to have out-neighbors anywhere.

Suppose that we know the vertex $u$ and delete all its out-edges.

Now we are looking for a vertex $v$ that "separates" the graph in two components, $V \ni v$ and $U \ni u$.

We can find $u$ in $O(n)$ time by trying all possibilities.  We can also find the strongly connected components in $O(n + m)$ time.  In this graph, we must find $v$ with the above property.  That can be done in linear time $O(n + m)$.  Hence it all runs in $O(n(n+m))$ time, which is at most $O(n^3)$.

Comment: You mean $u \in V \setminus U$? Because $U$ is a subset of $V$ so $U \setminus V$ is empty.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $u \in U$, you're of course right that $U \setminus V$ is empty!